# PYTHON - Create LAMBDA function inside function from user string to use on Pandas Apply

Tags: python, pandas, exec, apply

Ok I know many are going to ask "why do you let people create code?" and then say "do not use exec on pieces of string!" so here is the thinking:

- I would like my users to produce overrides by providing IF THEN ELSE statements
- That gets parsed into a Lambda function
- That gets then applied to a DataFrame using apply

This will be an example:

```
import pandas as pd

If = 'x.b > 2'
Then = 'x.a + 10'
Else = 'x.a'

s = f"MyFunc = lambda x: {Then} if {If} else {Else}"

Df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], 'b':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]})

def RunApply(Df, s):
    exec(s)
    return Df.apply(MyFunc, axis=1)

RunApply(Df, s)
```

And I have also tried:

```
def RunApply(Df, s):
    Compiled = compile(s, 'MyString', 'exec')
    exec(Compiled)
    return Df.apply(MyFunc, axis=1)
```

In both cases the output is:

```
NameError: name 'MyFunc' is not defined
```

If you run the exec() on the terminal it allows you to run Apply afterwards to the problem seems to be running it inside a Def. I am sure this has been resolved before but many of the solutions I find are customized to the specific problem that person had. In my case it is to produce the IF..THEN..ELSE code I want to run so happy to hear of other methods that may not involve EXEC.

Thanks!

UPDATE:

Amit recommended to run:

```
import pandas as pd

If = 'x.b > 2'
Then = 'x.a + 10'
Else = 'x.a'

s = f"lambda x: {Then} if {If} else {Else}"

Df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], 'b':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]})

def RunApply(Df, s):
    Compiled = compile(s, 'MyString', 'eval')
    MyFunc = eval(Compiled)
    return Df.apply(MyFunc, axis=1)

RunApply(Df, s)
```

This works but interested on other methods in case we are missing a proper pythonic way of doing this.

Comment: "I would like my users to produce overrides by providing IF THEN ELSE statements" What *problem do you solve* by doing this? How much flexibility do you really need? And why?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel because that is the requirement. This is a technical question not a philosophical one.

Comment: I have no idea what distinction you are trying to draw between "technical" and "philosophical" questions, but there is no such thing as solving a programming problem in the abstract without actually considering and **justifying** the requirements. Not unless you're doing a contest or assignment, anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `eval` method to evaluate your expression.
check below code:

```
s = f"lambda x: {Then} if {If} else {Else}"
MyFunc = eval(s)
```

check [eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) for more info